# sending file using sendmail

Tags: email, scripts, sendmail

I have a shell script that uses sendmail function to send email the code is as follows

```
mailalert(){
sendmail -F Sender-Name -it <<END_MESSAGE
To: Recipient@example.com
Subject: Subject

Message
END_MESSAGE
}
```

It gets executed whenever I call this function. Now I have a text file which I want to send using sendmail as attachment or as message in the email it sends. How can I do that? I have tried alot of tricks but nothing seems to work. Please Help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather strange but I used a different approach as while using `uuencode` it started executing but the cursor stuck at `begin 644 /path/to/file` so I used cat to send my file in the message body.

```
file=/path/to/file
mailalert(){
sendmail -F Sender-Name -it <<END_MESSAGE
To: Recipient@example.com
Subject: Subject

$(cat $file)
END_MESSAGE
}
```

The above code worked perfectly but when I saw the message in my web browser it was fine. But when I saw it in Thunderbird it was not shown correctly. It was like kind of encoded.

So, I'm keeping this question open until I dont find the right solution for now.

Comment: Your code doesn't work for me:-(

Answer (score 3):

Type `uuencode /path/filename.txt | sendmail -s "subject" user@domain` in your terminal to send mail.

- Replace "path" with the actual directory path in which the file to attach is located.
- Replace "filename.ext" with the actual file name and extension.
- Replace "subject" with the subject line you want the email to have.
- Replace "user@domain" with the recipient's email address.

this is the actual process to send mail with attachment.

add  `uuencode /path/filename.txt` before sendmail command in your script. I mean modify it as

```
mailalert(){
uuencode /path/filename.txt
sendmail -F Sender-Name -it <<END_MESSAGE
To: Recipient@example.com
Subject: Subject

Message
END_MESSAGE
}
```

hope that can help you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried it but it gives the error `uuencode: not found`.

Comment: och! ok `sudo apt-get install sharutils` then try again.@Tarun

Comment: I tried the approach but when executing the script it gives the message `begin 644 /path/filename.txt` and the cursor keeps on blinking.

Comment: @Tarun just look at here https://www.google.co.in/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=send+mail+attachments+begin+644&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=9XZVUs24Hs2Trgeg24HAAg

Answer (score 2):

I have created below script to attach a CSV File. The File is getting generated, but its truncating the header row /column name of CSV incorrectly and also there is one more file thats getting attached with the email, namely 'ATT0001.txt' with every email. Anything wrong that you could found out here?

### SCRIPT

```
(
echo "From:"$1;
echo "To:"$2;
echo "Subject:"$3;
echo "MIME-Version: 1.0";
echo "Content-Type:multipart/mixed; boundary=\"B835649000072104Jul07\"";

echo "--B835649000072104Jul07";
echo "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"UTF-8\"";
echo "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit";
echo "Content-Disposition: inline";
echo "";
echo "$4";

echo "--B835649000072104Jul07";
echo "Content-Type: text/csv";
echo "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64";
echo "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$5\"";
base64 "$5"

echo "--B835649000072104Jul07";
) | sendmail -t
```

Answer (score 1):

When sending mail, even from the command line, it is best to use a program which was designed for that purpose, rather than calling `sendmail` directly. A good all-around command-line e-mail client is `mutt`; in particular it has a command-line flag to attach files, which avoids the cumbersome use of `uuencode`:

```
echo Test | mutt -s Test -a image.jpg -- firas@fkraiem.org
```

As usual, see `man mutt` for usage information.

Answer (score 0):

After searching through numerous useless MAN pages and googling I finally came to this solution:
File to be sent: `test.csv`

On Ubuntu you will have uuencode (AIX), provided by the package `sharutils`, which you may need to install (the equivalent on Redhat is `mutt`).

```
uuencode test.csv test.csv | mail -v -s "Subject test" -r no-reply@mydomain.co.uk recepient@mydomain.co.uk
```

The biggest problem was to combine sendmail and attachment and at the same time setting the subject. Also on AIX I do not have the `-a attachment` option, like the LINUX Man page suggests.

You can also use `mailx` instead of `mail` with exactly the same parameters.

Comment: `mutt` is not "the equivalent" of `uuencode`. Also, `mailx` should always be preferred to `mail`, as the latter is non-standard.